# What is the main difference between SRFI 40 (deprecated) and 41?

Tags: scheme, lisp, sisc, srfi

In [SRFI 40](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-40/srfi-40.html) we can see it is deprecated and superseded by [SRFI 41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html). I'm using SISC where SRFI 40 is present but SRFI 41 isn't. I would like to know the main difference between them and can I use the SRFI 40 normally without fear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SRFI-40 leaks in some circumstances. See the `times3` function in the "Pitfalls" section of SRFI-41. See also the post-finalization discussion of SRFI-40.

It is possible to patch SRFI-40 to fix the problems, and some users have done so. I'm not sure if SISC has been patched. Also, David van Horn and Andre van Tonder have both made changes to the original reference implementation of SRFI-40, so I'm not sure but that may also work properly now. I personally avoid the problem and use SRFI-41.

Is there any reason SRFI-41 can't be used in SISC?

I am the author of SRFI-40 and SRFI-41.

Comment: The SISC implementation does not include the SRFI 45 fix, alas. (I just checked.) There's no reason why SRFI 41 can't be used with SISC to my knowledge, but it's been orphaned since February 2007, before SRFI 41 existed.

Comment: Thank you Philip, is an honor. The only reference I found is this in 2008: http://ehc.ac/p/sisc/mailman/message/19397436/